# how can i access to the intermediary table fields through the parent table in django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database, django-orm

this is my tables:

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    pass

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product , through='MidCartProduct')

class MidCartProduct(models.Model):
    class Meta : 
        unique_together = (('order_id' , 'product_id'))

    order_id = models.ForeignKey(Order , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

and so how can i access to the intermediary table `quantity` field through the `Order` table?
is that possible?

i tried to do this but not working :

```
>>> a = Order.objects.first().products.first()
>>> a.quantity
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Order' object has no attribute 'quantity'
```

Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate over the `midcartproduct_set` instead:

```
myorder = Order.objects.first()
for midcartproduct in myorder.midcartproduct_set.all():
    print(midcartproduct.quantity, midcartproduct.product_id)
```

Since you likely need all `Product`s, you better add a [**`.select_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for that:

```
myorder = Order.objects.first()
for midcartproduct in myorder.midcartproduct_set.select_related('product_id'):
    print(midcartproduct.quantity, midcartproduct.product_id)
```

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `product`, instead of <s>`product_id`</s>.